# Ordering output when two subshells write to stdout

Tags: shell-script, stdout, fifo, subshell, process-substitution

I have a command of the below form

```
input | tee >(subshell) | mainshell
```

Both subshell and mainshell writes to stdout. So their output is not synchronised. E.g.

```
echo "Hello\nWorld" | tee >(grep -o ell | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z') | grep orld | sed 's/orl/ORL/g'
```

The above command prints

```
ELL
WORLd
```

sometimes and

```
WORLd
ELL
```

other times.

Is there a simple way to make sure they are in expected order without having to using temporary files/named fifos? May be opening some file descriptor redirection would help?

**Update:**

By order, I mean output of the main shell and then the subshell (or vice versa). If it is deterministic one way or the other, I can swap them to my needs.

Same can be achieved by named fifo like below

```
mkfifo f1 f2
echo "Hello\nWorld" | tee >(grep -o ell | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' > f1) | grep orld | sed 's/orl/ORL/g' > f2 &
cat f1 f2
rm f1 f2
```

I was wondering if it is possible to avoid temporary fifos or files.

Comment: But what is the expected order? Do you mean you want the output lines in the same order as the input lines they correspond to? In some other situation, one might want all output from one process first, and all output from another process then. And in some other cases, the processes might respond to some external events, so you'd probably want the output in the same order those events happened (i.e. in the order the processes write them...)

Comment: In that first case, output lines corresponding to input lines, the problem is that there's no way for the system to know what corresponds to what. A simple sed might modify each line individually, so there's a 1:1 relation, but even grep removes lines... To do that, it's probably easier to replace the pair of programs with a single program that processes all lines, and keeps the output in whatever order it should be. Here, that could be done by replacing the greps with one awk, but that depends on the actual job

Comment: Your updated version does not seem to work if the output from `grep` is larger than a pipe block size. So this blocks: `seq 100000 | tee >(grep -o 1 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' > f1) | grep 2 | sed 's/orl/ORL/g' > f2 & cat f1 f2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Parallel has `--tee` and with `--keep-order` you can force the order to remain the same:

```
ell() {
  grep -o ell | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
}
orld() {
  grep orld | sed 's/orl/ORL/g'
}
export -f ell
export -f orld

echo "Hello\nWorld" | parallel -k --tee --pipe ::: ell orld
```

It does, however, use fifos and tempfiles behind the scene. But if your goal is simply to not having to deal with that yourself, then it might be a solution.

This solution uses tmpfiles, but they are unlinked almost immediately:

```
myfunc1() { grep -o ell | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'; }
myfunc2() { grep orld | sed 's/orl/ORL/g'; }

touch tmp1 tmp2
(
    echo "Hello\nWorld" |
        tee >( (rm tmp1; myfunc1) > tmp1 ) |
        (rm tmp2; myfunc2) > tmp2
    cat <&3
    cat <&4
) 3< tmp1 4< tmp2
```

Or shorter:

```
(
    rm tmp1 tmp2
    echo "Hello\nWorld" |
        tee >( grep -o ell | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' >&5 ) |
        grep orld | sed 's/orl/ORL/g' >&6
    cat <&3
    cat <&4
) 5> tmp1 6> tmp2 3< tmp1 4< tmp2
```

Comment: Thanks! Cool. I was mostly worried about temporary files lying around on failure. Your trick of deleting them immediately after opening a file descriptor should solve this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way to make sure they are in expected order without having to using temporary files/named fifos? May be opening some file descriptor redirection would help?

Not really. The `>(...)` and `...|...` subshells are running in parallel. Also, unix pipes/terminals/stream sockets/etc are *not* boundary-preserving -- there's no guarantee that a single write won't turn into multiple reads at the other end (or vice-versa).

In order to enforce some order, you can use advisory locking -- look at the [`flock(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) and [`flock(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) manpages. How to make that work depends a lot on how the `subshell` and `mainshell` programs work. Blindly locking non-collaborating programs easily leads to deadlocks (if it works at all).